# using ios::clear () if the ifstream is not going to be used anymore

Tags: c++, iostream

I am wondering if it is better to use `ios::clear()` or not in this code:

```
ifstream is;
is.open (file_name, ios::binary); 
if (is.fail()) 
    is.clear(), std::cout<<"error\n", std::exit(9);
```

If I am not using the ifstream anymore during the code (because of `std::exit()`), do I have to `ios::clear()` the stream anyway?

Comment: `clear()` won't have any effect if the stream isn't used further.

Comment: Also use braces `{}` please to group multiple statements instead of the comma operator!

Comment: Your 4th line is completely wrong with these commas `,`. Use braces `{ }` and semicolons at the end of each instruction.

Answer (score 0):

A call to `clear()` only clears the flags tested by `fail()`, `bad()`, and `eof()`.

It doesn't affect the stream in any other way.